# How to delay an action execution when use Task

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
Action<CancellationToken> act1 = tk1 => {
   //sleep for 5 seconds
   Console.WriteLine(...);
};

Task t1 = new Task(() => execute(act1));

t1.Start();
```

How to sleep inside action ? I tried with :

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

and

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: You would have to await `Task.Delay`. Also, don't use task constructor, but use `Task.Run`...

Comment: Use a Func that returns a task, make the function async and then you can use `await` with a `Task.Delay`

Comment: await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) or Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait()

Comment: So you tried and what happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

a new `Task` is created that is ran asynchronally by default. Hence your method will continue running independently from the `Task`. You have several option to synchronize to your `Task`.

If you are in an `async` method you can await the `Task`

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

otherwise, you may always use `Task.Wait`

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait();
```

this will block the method until the `Task` has finished running.

In your case you can make your Lambda `async`

```
Action<CancellationToken> act1 = async tk1 => {
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), tk1);
   Console.WriteLine(...);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Action<CancellationToken> act1 = async tk1 =>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
};

act1(default(CancellationToken));
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Action` delegate is the same as a `void` method. This makes using an `async` Actions the same as an `async void` which should be avoided.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Use a `Func` delegate that returns a `Task`, make the function async and then you can use `await` with a `Task.Delay`

```
Func<CancellationToken, Task> func1 = async token => {
    //sleep for 5 seconds
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), token);

    Console.WriteLine(...);
};

await func1(cancellationToken);
```